# SSL/TLS connections not working when deployed as Azure App Service

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-app-service-envrmnt

My team has an application that is currently deployed as an azure cloud service. The application works well, but after deploying as an app service (as a continuous web job), we're seeing many types of TLS connection failures. The TLS certificates are loaded into HTTPS clients and TCP socket clients. Why are these breaking when running as an app service?

**TCP:**

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
```

**HTTP:**

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
```

**Remote Certificate:**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
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
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: So, what's the remote certificate? Can it be validated with the stock Windows Server 2016 Root CAs (run `Get-Childitem cert:LocalMachine\root -Recurse` in Kudu)?

Comment: I added the remote certificate above. From a kudu powershell I can run `$cert.Verify()` and `Test-Certificate -Cert $cert`. Both of these are successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the App Settings in the portal for your app service

```
WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = *
```

- You still need this even if you're not loading certs in the SSL Certificates area of the portal
- This will impact the web jobs for that app service

Comment: That doesn't explain it, since that app setting pulls the certs you upload via the portal into the Personal store ("My" store) on the web worker, it has nothing to do with Trusted Root store. But if that makes it work then there's undocumented functionality in play.

Comment: Can you check what `Get-Childitem cert:LocalMachine\root -Recurse` returns now? Do you see thawte's thumbprint?

Comment: During testing, the service was actually connected to a proxy server, which was causing an additional problem with the handshake. I continued testing with a different service not using the proxy.

Comment: For my other service, the root CA was visible in the store and produced the same (TCP)exception. Like the other services we’re having a problem with, the client certificate is fetched from our repository (not through the portal). After AuthenticateAsClient is invoked, the exception appears. The ServerCertificateValidationCallback does not get invoked, but if looking at the [networking trace log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) it does appear to be evaluating the remote certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The
**thawte Primary Root CA - G3** certificate, with thumbprint`F18B538D1BE903B6A6F056435B171589CAF36BF2`, is not present in the Trusted Root store on the App Service worker, thus remote cert validation fails. The leaf cert (intermediate) is missing as well.

[image: Certification path]

[image: Comparing Trusted Root store, local vs Kudu]

Which doesn't make for terribly good news. I see two options, either [build a chain on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097671/how-to-verify-x509-cert-without-importing-root-cert) (which loads the missing CA cert from disk), or blindly return true from [`WebRequestHandler` and its `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` delegate property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872136/4148708).

NOTE:
I do have a working sample somewhere for the first part, let me know if i should look that up. In essence:

- Load the missing root CA from disk into X509Certificate2
- Build a chain and add it in
- Pass it to `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in `WebRequestHandler`

Comment: You should probably open a support case with Azure Support to add both the root CA and intermediate - i can see this cert comes bundled with Windows 10, so it must be a popular issuer.

Comment: we're moving forward with a support ticket, thanks a ton for the advice!

Comment: It turns out we needed to add `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = *` in the app settings on the portal, even though we're not loading our certificates into the portal's SSL Certificates area.

If this configuration is not set, the **client certificate** will fail validation. So the remote cert never had a chance to evaluate. This was also evident by the fact that the ServerCertificateValidationCallback function was not being invoked.

Comment: I think root certs are being downloaded as part of the handshake process. I tried reproducing the problem on my local machine by removing the thawte certs. But when I would run my sample the thawte cert would reinstall itself.

Comment: Root CAs are never downloaded as part of the TLS handshake, only leaf certs (intermediates) and only by clients that support AIA (Authority Information Access extension) - in practice this means just browsers. Think about it, if they also push you the root cert, they may as well self sign it or issue it through Joe's Crab Shack Certificate Authority.. it would still be valid.

Comment: Right, so they're probably not being downloaded, but the root CA does reappear into my store simply by running my sample exe. Because this causes speculation that the cert's presence in the store and it's trust are not exactly 1-to-1, I couldn't be 100% confident that searching for the root cert within the store would explain why the connection does not work