# C# .Net Validate a certificate against a X509Certificate2Collection; NOT the global sore

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

I have a X509Certificate2Collection, and I want to tell whether a given certificate is either in it or signed by a CA in the collection.

I do NOT want to reference the Windows certificate stores, which seems to be what every example shows.  This is for a secure application, and I do not care that CheapCertificate.Com has trusted some cert, only that specific CAs that I explicitly specify are valid.

Also, is it possible to use SslStream against anything other than the global store?  I could not see any parameter that set it.

To be clear, the wrong way is

```
foreach (X509Certificate2 trustedIssuer in trustedCerts) {
  if (trustedIssuer.Subject == certificate.Issuer) {...
```

Comment: You would usually compare the thumbprints of two certificates. See the remarks under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.equals?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate_Equals_System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate_

Answer (score 0):

The following describes it.  A bit of work, create your own chain, put all the certs in, see if it validates.

[How to verify X509 cert without importing root cert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097671/how-to-verify-x509-cert-without-importing-root-cert)